# Get list of all files with the user who checked in the latest version in TFS

Tags: version-control, tfs

Is there a way in TFS to get a list of files under source control with the user who checked in the latest version/version you have locally.

The closest functionality to this that i can find is in the source control explorer window you can see each files with the latest check-in date, but not with the user who checked it in.

Comment: Two things. 1) is this for a given folder, recursively down from a point in source control. 2) do you mind using the TFS API to produce a list, or are you after a more complete tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way currently from the VS Source control explorer. The best you can get is using the Web TFS version. You will see the name of the user in the comments section (in orange in the image below) along with changset # and any comment.

[image]

If that doesn't work for you somehow then you can either use TFS Api or SQL query against TFS DB. Following SQL should give you the result.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    V.ChildItem AS [FileName],
    I.DisplayName AS [ChangedBy],
    CS.CreationDate AS [ChangeDate]
FROM tbl_Changeset CS
INNER JOIN tbl_Identity I 
    ON I.IdentityID = CS.OwnerID
INNER JOIN tbl_Version V 
    ON V.VersionFrom = CS.ChangesetID
```